# Difference between @Async and executor

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I can't find any reason for using executor instead of @Async Spring annotation.
Can someone explain me what is the difference between @Async and executors?

Comment: Not everyone uses Spring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executors are more complex to use, but offer a lot of flexibility on how the function is run.  For example, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` has a queue of the work it needs to do.  If that queue is full, it can force the caller to run the work to keep the queue from overflowing.

@Async is designed to be simpler to use, but takes aways a lot of the control you have in how the execution happens.  Also, the code becomes Spring specific, so it wouldn't be appropriate to use in a more widely distributed library.